# On the $p$-adic logarithm

Tags: analysis, p-adic-number-theory

It is well known that $p$-adic logarithm define an isomorphism from $B(1,p^{-1/p-1})$ to $B(0,p^{-1/p-1})$. I would like to know if is it possible to extend somehow this logarithm to the set of $x$ such that $|x|_p=1$. My idea would be to find a minmal $n$ such that $x^n \in B(1,p^{-1/p-1})$ and define $\log_p(x)=\frac{\log_p(x^n)}{n}$.
But I am not able to find such a $n$. So I would like to know if it is indeed possible to extend $\log_p$ to this set.

Comment: There is a standard extension of the $p$-adic logarithm to $\Bbb Q_p^*$.

Comment: Yes, but I would like somehow that the $log_p$ stay an isomorphism on my set.

Comment: This is one of my previous questions, which looks related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353389/why-do-we-define-the-mathfrakp-adic-logarithm-on-a-mathfrakp-adic-numb

Comment: Okay, yes it is related, but my question would be how exactly do you extend it to the group of principal unit ?

Comment: So you can define $\log_p$ as a power series on the set $\{x: |x - 1|_p \lt 1\}$, and you can extend its domain to $\mathbb{Q}_p^*$ by defining $\log_p(p) = 0$, and in general for $x = up^n$ you would have $\log_p(x) = \log_p(u)$, where $u$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$. Each unit can be written as $u = \zeta u'$ where $\zeta$ is a root of unity and $u'$ is a principal unit. Then $\log_p(u) = \log_p(\zeta) + \log_p(u') = \log_p(u')$ since the log is zero on the roots of unity.

Comment: Hmm sure, but by doing so I will no more get an isomorphism right ?

Comment: That might work. If $a \in \{1, \ldots, p-1\}$ is such that $|x - a|_p \lt 1$ then you can let $n = |a|$ (order of $a$ modulo $p$) so that $x^n \in B(1, 1/p)$ (assuming $|x|_p = 1$).

Comment: Okay I will try to computate this in details and put the result here after. Thanks !

Comment: I don't think the logarithm usually gives you an isomorphism because it is not injective (any root of unity in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ will be mapped to $0$). It is injective on the principal units though.

Comment: But actually it's an isomorphism from the ball I described in my question so the goal is to find the good power for each element of the group of principal unit to make it fall in the ball.

Comment: Isomorphism of what? Sets? Topological spaces? Groups? Also, I assume but you have not explicitly stated that the balls are inside $\Bbb Q_p$ (as opposed to some extension thereof) - is that right?

Comment: Of groups would be good, yeah the balls are Inside $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $p>2,$ it is a standard fact that

$\{x\in \Bbb Q_p: |x|_p=1\} = \Bbb Z_p^\times \simeq \mu_{p-1}(\Bbb Q_p) \times \{x\in \Bbb Q_p: |x-1|_p <1\}$

as topological groups. The second factor on the right hand side are the principal units, often denoted $U_1$, and since the $p$-adic absolute value on $\Bbb Q_p$ takes only integer powers of $p$ as value, it is identical to your $B(1, p^{-\frac{1}{p-1}})$.

To extend the logarithm $log:U_1 \rightarrow \Bbb Q_p$ to the full set $\Bbb Z_p^\times$, you therefore "only" have to define it on $\mu_{p-1}(\Bbb Q_p)$, the $(p-1)$-th roots of unity. Indeed, the only $n$ you have to choose for your proposed extension formula is $n=p-1$. However, if you want the extension to be a a group homomorphism (from the multiplicative group on the left to the additive on the right), you'll have to define it as $log(\zeta) = 0$ for all $\zeta \in \mu_{p-1}(\Bbb Q_p)$, because those $\zeta$'s are torsion, whereas the only torsion element on the right hand side is $0$. (Or, using your extension formula, $log(\zeta) = \frac{log(\zeta^{p-1})}{p-1} = \frac{log(1)}{p-1} = 0$.)

In particular, an extension of the logarithm to $\{x\in \Bbb Q_p: |x|_p=1\}$ cannot be at the same time a group homomorphism and injective.

Comment: Thak you very much that's very clear !!

Comment: Do you have any references that talk about all this results ? I would be very interested to read them.

Comment: Any book about $p$-adics (F. Gouvea, A. Robert) and/or local fields (Serre, or corresponding chapters in Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory* or *Class Field Theory*). There's probably even dozens of decent lecture notes out there. Also, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/73565/96384 and  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1298669/96384.

Comment: Super ! Thanks !